# ¿Cómo puedo extraer solo determinadas columnas de un csv y crear un DataFrame con ellas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, ciencia-de-datos

Tengo un DataFrame 16 x 16 que obtengo a partir de un archivo csv. Quiero extraer solo tres columnas para trabajar con esos datos.

Los nombres de las columnas que quiero extraer son:

> candidate_name;disbursement_amount ;disbursement_date

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué debo utilizar o cómo puedo hacer para extraer las tres columnas y ponerlas juntas, para solo trabajar con esos datos?

Comment: ¿Estás leyendo los datos de un csv por casualidad?

Comment: Si, estoy leyendo los datos de un CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes resolver el problema de esta manera:

`dfNuevo = pandas.DataFrame()
 dfNuevo['candidate_name'] = DfViejo['candidate_name']
 dfNuevo['disbursement_amount'] = DfViejo['disbursement_amount']
 dfNuevo['disbursement_date'] = DfViejo['disbursement_date']`

Otra forma seria por ejemplo:

`dfNuevo = DfViejo[['candidate_name', 'disbursement_amount','disbursement_date']].copy()`

Recuerda que en python cuando haces copias de variables debes saber cuando son referencias al elemento y cuando son copias un ejemplo de esto es el siguiente.

`tango = [1,2,3,4,5] #Creas una lista
pepe = tango #Aqu'i no creas una copias creas una referencia
pipo = tango[:] #Aqu'i copias absolutamente todos los valores
pepe[0] = 666 # aqu'i modificas el valor 0 tanto para tango como para pepe
print(tango) # debe imprimir 666,2,3,4,5
print(pepe)  # debe imprimir 666,2,3,4,5
print(pipo)  # debe imprimir 1,2,3,4,5`

Answer (score 2):

Como lees los datos desde un csv, en Pandas usando [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) basta con que uses el parámetro `usecols` pasandole un iterable con los nombres o índices de las columnas que deseas cargar:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = StringIO('''\
colA;candidate_name;colF;disbursement_amount;colG;disbursement_date
1;dad;aaa;145;46;10/01/2018
2;fff;yff;16;145;11/01/2018
3;hrf;rrr;96;62;12/01/2018
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', usecols=("candidate_name",
                                        "disbursement_amount",
                                        "disbursement_date"))
```

> **Nota:** `StringIO` se usa solo para emular un fichero csv. Si se usa Python 2 y se quiere reproducir el ejemplo, se debe cambiar el import por `from StringIO import StringIO`.